# what is error with the following simple r code?

Tags: r, function, environment

what is error with the following code?

```
 odd_even <-function(x)
 {
  {if (x %% 2 == 0) y <- TRUE
   else  y<-FALSE
 }
 y
 }
 odd_even(c((-5:5),2,-2))
```

it shows following answer

```
*[1] FALSE
```

Warning message:

> In if (x%%2 == 0) y <- TRUE else y <- FALSE :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

Comment: `if` wants a vector of length 1. You are feeding it a vector of length 13 (if I'm counting right). That is what the warning *the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used* means.

Comment: Use this: `odd_even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0`.

Comment: `if ()` can evaluate only one element. `ifelse()` can work on vectors.